# Laravel 5.3 update to remote apache server

Tags: apache, laravel

I have an Ubuntu machine in Azure with my Laravel project and it works good. Today, I used Laravel Auth on my localhost environment and it works too. I save the data in a local database.

Now I need to update my Laravel project in Azure. It is just update the project or I need some configuration on virtual machine to work with the local database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you should focus is you have an Ubuntu instalation, either it is on DigitalOcean, AWS or Azure, all are same. 
Secondly, consider installing [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) on your local machine. That will assure you that the server and local development have all the same components, so you can be pretty sure that if it works on your localhost, it will work in your server.

As for your question, please conpare the verion of the components on your system (local) and server. If both are same, everything would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On server, in ubuntu machine i install mysql with username and password. I will put this username and password on .env file in laravel. It is right?

Comment: No, it depends on other things like Apache version, MySQL version, PHP versions, etc. For example, if you use Laravel with PHP 5.5 on your server and PHP 5.6 on your local, a lot of things working on local will not run on server.
.env file is just a configuration. It's configuation will ensure code gets docked with other stuffs like MySQL. But if version is unsupported, it is a totally different thing.

Comment: Ok. i already have my laravel project on cloud a few days and it's work very good. Now i will test run the database because until today i dont have local database.

Comment: I have this error when i try to register a user in laravel project on ubuntu machine (azure)

queryexception 

Error: could not find driver (SQL: insert into `users` (`FirstName`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)